# using gstring to access list property element

Tags: groovy

Using GStrings one can access the properties of the object, including nested properties. But how to access the n'th element inside a list property?

```java
class Foo {
   List<Bar> elements
}
class Bar {
  String version
}
```

I need to access version property in Foo.elements object for a specific index using GString.
Tried below code without success.

```
def property = "elements[0].version"
fooObject."$property" fails to identify the property
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So there are three ways in which I think this problem can be solved depending upon how much flexibility is allowed

```
class Foo {
   List<Bar> elements
}
class Bar {
  String version
}
```

Let's say `fooObject` is the object of `Foo`, e.g.:

```
def fooObject = new Foo(elements:[new Bar(version:1), new Bar(version:2)])
```

1. If this is possible for you:

   ```
   println fooObject."elements"[1]."version"
   ```
2. Otherwise, put everything in a string and then interpolate:

   ```
   println "${fooObject.elements[1].version}"
   ```
3. Ultimately, if both of the above don't fly for you:

   ```
   def property='elements[1].version'
   def expr = 'fooObject.' + property
   println Eval.me('fooObject', fooObject, expr)
   ```

The last one makes the `fooObject` available as `fooObject` to the expression being evaluated and evaluates the expression.

Comment: The usual warning with eval applies, running unknown code can lead to issues ;-)

Comment: Yeah and that's why it's placed third :)

Comment: Eval worked perfect in my scenario. Its for test code. So was good with Eval. Thnx.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, it could be:

```
def prop1 = "elements"
def prop2 = "version"

fooObject."$prop1"[0]."$prop2"
```

Lengthy and generic one would be using `inject`:

```
class Foo {
   List<Bar> elements
}
class Bar {
  String version
}

def fooObject = new Foo(elements: [new Bar(version: '1'), 
                                   new Bar(version: '2'), 
                                   new Bar(version: '3')])

def fetchVersion(property, fooObject) {
    property.tokenize(/./).inject(fooObject) {obj, elem -> 
        if(elem.contains(/[/)){
            def var = elem.tokenize(/[]/)
            obj?."${var[0]}".getAt("${var[1]}".toInteger()) 
        } else {
            obj?."$elem" 
        }
    }
}

assert fetchVersion("elements[0].version", fooObject) == '1'
assert fetchVersion("elements[1].version", fooObject) == '2'
assert fetchVersion("elements[2].version", fooObject) == '3'
assert fetchVersion("elements[7].version", fooObject) == null
```